# Python convert timedeltas into hours in string format

Tags: python, string, date, time

I have a timedelta object which is 3457 hours

```
timedelta(hours=3457)
```

I want to represent it in "HH:MM" format, which is "3457:00"

I do:

```
from datetime import datetime
hours = timedelta(hours=3457)
hours_string =  time.strftime("%H:%M", time.gmtime(hours.seconds))
print hours_string

"01:00"
```

How can I get "3457:00"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note that 3457:00 is a nonsensical format. The "hour-colon-minutes" format is used in dates and times, and the hour then can't reasonably be any higher than 23. A more reasonable format is: 3457h 0m.

You can get it like this:

```
from datetime import timedelta

delta = timedelta(hours=3457)
minutes, seconds = divmod(delta.seconds, 60)
hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
hours += delta.days * 24

print '%sh %sm' % (hours, minutes)
```

Of course, an easier way is this:

```
from datetime import timedelta

delta = timedelta(hours=3457)
print delta
```

But that will give you "144 days, 1:00:00", which is a sane format, but not what you want.

Comment: Thanks,  but in Excel we can add hours and get a value like "3457:45". Best regards

Comment: @alwbtc: Well, this is not Excel, so there is no need to be obtusely terse. But you can of course use that format if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

As the [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#datetime.timedelta) documentation notes, only *days*, *seconds* and *microseconds* are stored internally -- which means you'll have to manually convert them to the units you want (hours and minutes). Here's one way to do that:

```
from datetime import timedelta

d = timedelta(hours=3457, minutes=42)
wholehours, seconds = divmod(d.seconds, 60*60)
wholeminutes = seconds//60
deltahours = d.days*24 + wholehours
print('{:d}:{:02d}'.format(deltahours, wholeminutes))
# 3457:42
```

Here's a simpler alternative that produces the same result:

```
def deltatime_hours_mins(dt, sep=':'):
    secs = int(dt.total_seconds())
    return '{:d}{}{:02d}'.format(secs//3600, sep, secs//60 % 60)

print(deltatime_hours_mins(d))
```

Comment: That will give you hours:seconds, which hardly can be intended.